# SQL left join one table to multiple fields with priority

Tags: sql, ms-access

e.g. if my data table is

```
ID,ColumnA, ColumnB, ColumnC
--------------------------------
1,ABC,111,DEF
2,111,ABC,DEF
3,111,111,DEF
```

I also have a mapping table

```
Codekey, Result
---------------------------
ABC,OK1
DEF,OK2
```

What I want to achieve is mapping table left join data table with ColumnA,ColumnB and ColumnC at the same time.

If ColumnA can left join mapping table result, then subject to ColumnA

Else, the result is subject to ColumnB

If ColumnA and ColumnB didn't left join mapping table result, then subject to ColumnC.

So the left join priority is ColumnA>ColumnB>ColumnC

Following is my desired result:

```
 ID,ColumnA, ColumnB, ColumnC,Result
 -----------------------------------
 1,ABC,111,DEF,OK1 
 2,111,ABC,DEF,OK1
 3,111,111,DEF,OK2
```

Any idea ? I've tried to search old questions but seems no similar case.
Thank you! :)

Ken

Comment: LEFT JOIN three times. For cola, colb and colc.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM DATA D
LEFT JOIN MAPPING M ON (CASE WHEN D.ColumnA=M.Codekey THEN D.ColumnA=M.Codekey
WHEN D.ColumnB=M.Codekey THEN D.ColumnB=M.Codekey
WHEN D.ColumnC=M.Codekey THEN D.ColumnC=M.Codekey
END)
```

You can use **`CASE WHEN`** for on condition.

try above code, this will help you.

Comment: Thanks for you answer! I still got issue on my work and I've post the details in another new answer. I am appreciate so much if you could take a look and see if you can comment on it.

Answer (score 1):

It might be simpler to use *Nz*:

```sql
SELECT 
    DataTable.ID, 
    DataTable.ColumnA, 
    DataTable.ColumnB, 
    DataTable.ColumnC, 
    Nz([A]![Result],Nz([B]![Result],[C]![Result])) AS MapResult
FROM 
    ((DataTable 
LEFT JOIN MappingTable AS A 
    ON DataTable.ColumnA = A.Codekey) 
LEFT JOIN MappingTable AS B 
    ON DataTable.ColumnB = B.Codekey) 
LEFT JOIN MappingTable AS C 
    ON DataTable.ColumnC = C.Codekey;
```

Comment: @Ken . . . This is the best answer -- both in terms of functionality and performance.

Comment: Hello Gustav and Gordon, yes, it works perfectly. Thank you for your great assistance indeed. Good day. Cheers, Ken